# P(Neither Type A nor Type B)

Tags: probability

$$
P(A^{+}) = 1/4\\
P(A^{-}) = 1/16\\
P(B^{+}) = 1/5\\
P(B^{-}) = 1/20
$$
$A^{+}$ and $A^{-}$ is type $A+$ and $A-$
$B^{+}$ and $B^{-}$ is type $B+$ and $B-$

I would like to find the P(Neither type A nor type B). What I did was:

$$
P(A) = P(A^{+}) + P(A^{-}) = \frac 14 + \frac 1{16} = \frac5{16}\\
P(B) = P(B^{+}) + P(B^{-}) = \frac 15 + \frac 1{20} = \frac5{20}\\
P(\lnot A\land\lnot B) = 1 - (P(A) + P(B)) = 1 - (\frac5{16} + \frac5{20}) = 1 - \frac9{16} = \frac7{16}.
$$
I am not 100% sure if this is right. Could someone please confirm?

Comment: Looks good to me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac14 + \frac1{16}+\frac15+\frac1{20} = \frac9{16}$ as you say.

On the assumption that the four types are mutually exclusive, the probability of none of them is indeed $\displaystyle1- \frac9{16}=\frac7{16}$.